# регулярное выражение, удаляющее комментарии. Perl

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Задание: есть текст, допустим `abc/*de/*f*/m*/x` с комментариями, которые нужно удалить регулярным выражением, причем, если в комментарии есть вложенный комментарий, то сначала надо удалить его.

У меня получилось что-то такое:

```
while ($string =~ m|/\*(.*?)\*/|)  {
   $string =~ s|(/\*((?!(.*?/\*).*?).*?)\*/.*?)|$_|;
   print ""$string\n;
}
```

Получим:

```
abc/*de/*f*/m*/x
abc/*dem*/x
abcx
```

И все вроде работает хорошо, но если в примере будут идти два комментария подряд, допустим теперь строка `abc/*de/*f*/*/x`, то программа зациклится.

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: Вот как раз смысл задания в том, чтобы была n-мерная вложенность, и её надо вырезать, начиная с самого вложенного комментария.

Comment: @Mike хорошо, а как можно подправить регулярку, чтобы не было зацикливания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string="abc/*def/*gh/*j*/ik*/lmn*/opq/*r/*st*/uvw*/xyz";
print "$string\n\n";
while($string=~m|/\*.*?\*/|) {           # До тех пор пока комментарии остались
 $string=~s|/\*((?!.*?(?0)).*?)\*/||;  # Вырезаем один
 print "$string\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
abc/*def/*gh/*j*/ik*/lmn*/opq/*r/*st*/uvw*/xyz

abc/*def/*gh/*j*/ik*/lmn*/opq/*ruvw*/xyz
abc/*def/*gh/*j*/ik*/lmn*/opqxyz
abc/*def/*ghik*/lmn*/opqxyz
abc/*deflmn*/opqxyz
abcopqxyz
```

Смысл вырезающей регулярки:

```
/\*              # Комментарий открылся
 (               # Выделяющая группа
  (?!.*?(?0))    # Внутри которой не содержится еще одно выражение
  .*?
 )
\*/              # Комментарий закрылся
```

Основа в ссылке `(?0)`, которая на свое место подставляет текст всего выражения целиком, рекурсивно.